# Find! condition in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been following rails casts #221, i author using `find_by_somefield!` with "!". What does that mean in context of ActiveRecord find condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error.

reference: [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders)

Answer (score 1):

see the below link. You will get the answer.

http://rorguide.blogspot.in/2011/06/active-record-finder-methods-dynamic.html